# Increasing performance of Heroku Dynos startup with the Help of Caching or a CDN (e.g. cloudflare.com)

Tags: caching, heroku, cdn

I am wondering how to increase the startup of idling `Heroku Dynos` ([Heroku Devcenter on Idling](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-idling)). Long Story short: If your `Webapplication` is not visited for a Hour, the will shutdown and if a user is visiting the site again, the `Dyno` will need to start again.

I did some research on this and I know you could ping your application every hour, but I really don't like to trick the heroku guys. So I am looking for another solution.

I found some people recommending a `CDN` (`Content Delivery Network` e.g. [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/)). I am wondering how this would work? My `Webapplication` starts with a static `Welcome Page`, from where you can click a `Link` to dynamically created `WebPage`. So I am wondering if it would be possible to visit my `Webapplication` on `www.example.com` and get the content of the static `Welcome Page`, but the `CDN` is requesting my `Webapplication` on updates, therefore the `Dyno` would begin to start. If a user now clicks on the Link to the dynamically created `WebPage` the `Dyno`would have already started.

Maybe it would also work with Caching? Do you have any Ideas on this topic?

Is this possible or does `Heroku` offer something like this?

Answer (score 1):

> but I really don't like to trick the heroku guys

If you're worried about not tricking the Heroku guys, just up your Dynos to 2 or more :)

The idling only takes affect on apps with one Dyno.

I don't think pinging the site using a service such as [Pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com/) is a bad idea anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well I will upgrad to 2 `Dynos` if I will need my Traffic requires it. I am also aware of the fact, that a app only idles if your on a free plan. Well heroku needs to pay for the running `Dynos` as well, because they rent it on the `AWS - EC2 Infrastructure` (As far as I am concerned). If everybody is pinging their Websites, Heroku probably stop offering you free plans. That's why I am trying to do Trick with external Caching or something like this.

Comment: Pinging only keeps the Dyno from going idle. It doesn't provide scale. If you start getting more traffic you will need to add additional Dynos anyway. Caching is not really appropriate to this situation. If you find a solution, I would be interested to hear it :)

Comment: I will. But it does not seem to be possible (according to the answers :D)

Comment: After all this was no exact Match to my Question, but this seems to be the best way to do this.